# TileControl DevExpress from DB

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I need to populate various tileItems by retrieving information from a BindingSource.
How can I proceed? Could I also manage the secondary elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the TileControl, I suggest you use the GridControl's [TileView](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Tile.TileView) which specially designed to displays data-records as read-only tiles. There is a number of layout modes available for this View: default (one or multiple columns/rows), list (without spaces between records) and [Kanban](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117616/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/views/tile-view/kanban-board).
You can start with TileView from the [Tutorial: Tile View - Basics](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114710/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/getting-started/walkthroughs/tile-view/tutorial-tile-view-basics).